# USB Ports not woking after fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: usb, 18.04

I have recently switched to Ubuntu and decided to install the latest 18.04 version. I managed to find my way through all the hacks and fixes to get it up and running. However, I'm stuck with my USB ports that are not working at all. I have tried switching between both ports, but no luck. However, please note that launching and booting Ubuntu from USB works. However, I can't use the ports after the os has been launched. Here is my configuration.

```
$ lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0c03]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell GeForce GT 630M [1028:054d]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4460]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
09:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [1028:054d]
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

---

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -iFe usb:
[  126.962108] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[  126.962114] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu
[  126.962115] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS L421X/08HDPJ, BIOS A16 12/17/2013
[  126.962115] Call Trace:
[  126.962117]  <IRQ>
[  126.962123]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[  126.962126]  __report_bad_irq+0x35/0xc0
[  126.962128]  note_interrupt+0x24b/0x2a0
[  126.962130]  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x54/0x80
[  126.962131]  handle_irq_event+0x3b/0x60
[  126.962133]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x75/0x130
[  126.962135]  handle_irq+0x20/0x30
[  126.962137]  do_IRQ+0x4e/0xd0
[  126.962139]  common_interrupt+0x84/0x84
[  126.962140]  </IRQ>
[  126.962143] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x2f0
[  126.962143] RSP: 0018:ffffa9b0406cfe68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffdb
[  126.962145] RAX: ffff9d11df2e2880 RBX: 0000001d8f87d759 RCX: 000000000000001f
[  126.962146] RDX: 0000001d8f87d759 RSI: fffffffb6108e5e9 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  126.962147] RBP: ffffa9b0406cfea8 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000001
[  126.962147] R10: ffffa9b0406cfe38 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9d11df2ec860
[  126.962148] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffffffff93f71b58 R15: 0000000000000000
[  126.962150]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x97/0x2f0
[  126.962152]  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[  126.962154]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
[  126.962156]  do_idle+0x18c/0x1f0
[  126.962157]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[  126.962160]  start_secondary+0x1ab/0x200
[  126.962162]  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
[  126.962163] handlers:
[  126.962166] [<00000000a245318f>] usb_hcd_irq
[  126.962171] [<00000000930b43ed>] sdhci_irq [sdhci] threaded [<000000008281e962>] sdhci_thread_irq [sdhci]
[  126.962202] [<00000000963ed05c>] ironlake_irq_handler [i915]
[  126.962206] [<00000000a4a8b34b>] mei_me_irq_quick_handler [mei_me] threaded         [<00000000a0bb2d13>] mei_me_irq_thread_handler [mei_me]
[  126.962211] [<00000000e18ac2bd>] rtl8169_interrupt [r8169]
[  126.962213] Disabling IRQ #16
[ 1681.986762] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[ 1681.986767] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32.
[ 1681.986770] usb usb3-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

---

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2899 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop1    7:1    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop2    7:2    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop3    7:3    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop4    7:4    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop5    7:5    0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop6    7:6    0   4.9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/42
loop7    7:7    0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop8    7:8    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
loop9    7:9    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop10   7:10   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/199
loop11   7:11   0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop12   7:12   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/117
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   4.8G  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  19.1G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   9.5G  0 part /var
├─sda7   8:7    0 381.5G  0 part /home
└─sda8   8:8    0   4.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0  29.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0     8G  0 part
```

---

```
$ cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:          7          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:          0          0          0       6460  IR-IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  8:          0          1          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          5          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          0          0     169207          0  IR-IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
 16:          0          0        192     199990  IR-IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, mmc0, i915, mei_me, enp7s0
 18:     202567          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC  18-fasteoi   iwlwifi
 19:      23972          0       9451          0  IR-IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   rtsx_pci, ahci[0000:00:1f.2]
 20:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC  20-edge      smo8800
 21:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC  21-fasteoi   xhci-hcd:usb3
 22:          0       1055          0          0  IR-IO-APIC  22-fasteoi   snd_hda_intel:card0
 23:          0          0          0        164  IR-IO-APIC  23-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 24:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI   0-edge      dmar0
 25:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI   1-edge      dmar1
NMI:         10          8         11          9   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     124279      91094     126994     116660   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:         10          8         11          9   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:        136        167        206       3033   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:      17932      20329      14384      10358   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:      50126      45306      42931      41791   Function call interrupts
TLB:      42519      36490      34155      33556   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          7          8          8          8   Machine check polls
HYP:          0          0          0          0   Hypervisor callback interrupts
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
NPI:          0          0          0          0   Nested posted-interrupt event
PIW:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

I also tried looking into other similar threads, but wasn't able to find anything that could help so far.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0c03]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'`? Thanks.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for helping me out. I also added in the output to the command you have recommended.